# match string with database values in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a database table 'travel'.There is a column called **travelclasss** and it contains values '**economy,business,firstclass**'.I have a form

```
<form id="search-form">
        FROM<input type="text" name="f"><br>
        TO<input type="text" name="t"><br>
        CLASS<input type="text" name="c"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

If I enter in my form CLASS field either economy 'or' business 'or' firstclass I want to check these names are in my database **travelclasss** column.

I need implement it in django. How to check particular name is present in database using django.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Travel(models.Model):
    TRAVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('EC', 'economy'),
        ('BS', 'business'),
        ('FC', 'firstclass'),
    )
    travelclasss = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                    choices=TRAVEL_CHOICES,
                                    default='EC')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from yourapp.models import Travel

class TravelForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Travel
         fields = ['travelclasss']
```

Then, you will have a drop-down box to choose from.

Here is [more doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) on ModelForms.
Here is [more doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) on Choices.